# How to get one week older tweets using tweepy?

Tags: python, tweepy

I am getting tweets from the user using twitter search api i.e. tweepy. I get tweets of one day but now i want to get one week older tweets. I have tried to get older tweets by this code but i am unable to get old tweets. Any help will be highly appreciated

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="#afridi",count=100,\
                       lang="en",\
                       since_id=2016-05-25).items():
print tweet.created_at, tweet.text
```

Answer (score 0):

No other way if you do not know the since_id of the tweet of just one week older tweet. To get older tweets you can let the code run for a while and check the dates of the tweets you are getting. Process those tweets as you want which are 1 week older or so.
Else if you know since_id then put the since_id.